# Multiple Default Website IIS

Tags: iis-7, web-hosting

Right now, i have my default website in my server. Here is the binding details

```
Port : 80
HostName : (Blank)
IP Address: *
```

And then my custom Application

```
Port : 80
Hostname : myPortal.com
IP Address : *
```

If I browse my application with myPortal.com, its coming up fine and I dont have any issues. Here is the Problem. For application availability purpose, i have four failover servers and the application is configured in the same way for each server.

If I want to browse my application with server name in order to find when one of the server is having issues, i m not able to do it

say for eg, if i browse, myPortal.com, its working but if i want to browse myserverA.com, its going to default website

**Approach 1 which i tried:**
To Overcome this issue, i made host name field as blank for my custom application and updated it with localhost for IIS Default website. 
**Doubt 1:**
It served my purpose but i scare if i have to host one more application in the server default port, i will be getting into trouble. Are there any best approach to solve this issue

**Approach 2 which i tried**
I left the host name as blank for Default Web site and had myPortal.com for my custom Application and then edited the IP address field for my custom Application. I changed the IP address from "All Unassigned" to "Server IP address"

**Doubt 2:**
It served by purpose of browsing my application with myPortal.com and myServer.com but what is the impact of changing the IP from "All unassinged" to "Specific Address"?
Also, in future, if i host one more application in default port with different host name, how would i be accessing that server with server name or IP name?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what's desired.

To access a certain site with host name on a specific server, you can go and modify hosts file, add an entry for the host name and point to the IP of he target server. Then in your browser you can access it correctly.

Comment: Problem with this is, if i access with server name, then it points to servers default website. Means IIS default page appears. May be you could give a try on ur local

Comment: You cannot use the server name. You must type the correct host name so that the browser send out proper HTTP requests and IIS can pass it on to the proper site. The default site is there to catch all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which finally worked out

In the custom application, under EditBindings, add one more binding
Leave the hostname as blank for the new binding. Add a port number other than 8080

It helped to solve below issues

- I m able to access my custom application through myportal.com and 
  Also in scenarios, when i have issue with one of the shared servers,
  i can try accessing each of the server site individually through
  serverNameA:port

So in future, if i want to host one more application in the default port, i have to register new host name for that server and will add one more additional binding for browsing with server name

Comment: Just note that there will be a cost to have additional bindings.